# Why "studentRequired < m" returns true in minimum allocation problem

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-search

In Book allocation [problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/allocate-minimum-number-pages/) in `isPossible()` function why even if `studentsRequired` are less than `m` (students we need to allocate books for ) results the `curr_min` to be a viable sollution and we `return true` ? Does't it mean that books are not allocated to all the students ?

for example if the array is `[5, 82, 52, 66, 16, 37, 38, 44, 1, 97, 71, 28, 37, 58, 77, 97, 94, 4, 9]`
with `m = 16`. Maximum value `studentsRequired` gets is 13. does't it mean that only 13 students got the books but 16 should have ?

here is the code in JS, for other languages ( cpp, java, python ) please get to this GFG [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/allocate-minimum-number-pages/)

```js
function isPossible(arr, n, m, curr_min) {
    let studentsRequired = 1;
    let curr_sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > curr_min) return false;
        if (curr_sum + arr[i] > curr_min) {
            studentsRequired++;
            curr_sum = arr[i];
            if (studentsRequired > m) return false;
        } else {
            curr_sum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function findPages(arr, n, m) {
    let sum = 0;
    if (n < m) return -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += arr[i];
    let start = 0,
        end = sum;
    let result = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    while (start <= end) {
        let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        if (isPossible(arr, n, m, mid)) {
            result = Math.min(result, mid);
            end = mid - 1;
        } else start = mid + 1;
    }
    return result;
}

const ans = findPages(
    [5, 82, 52, 66, 16, 37, 38, 44, 1, 97, 71, 28, 37, 58, 77, 97, 94, 4, 9],
    19,
    16
);
console.log("Ans : ", ans);
```

What i think is happening => 
When i dry run the code for test case `arr = [10,20,30,40]` with `m = 4`, the result is S1 = [10,20], S2 = [30], S3 = [40] and we did not allocated a book to S4.
Are we assuming that students with more books (like S1 had [10,20]) can transfer there last book, 20 in this case to there right student ? And then S2 will have [20,30] so 30 will be then transferred to S3 and in the end S3 will tranfer its last book to S4 making the condition "Every student must have a book" true as now S1 = [10], S = [20], S3 = [30], S4 = [40]? Or its something else ?